# Arduino long long int doc

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm a newbie to Arduino, using the UNO. I've stumbled across the "long long int" data type (int64_t). I haven't seen it mentioned in any of the instructional docs I've found. For instance, https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage doesn't list it.

Is there some site or book that systematically discusses the entire Arduino Sketch language, including all the data types?

Answer (score 2):

Typedefs such as int64_t are declared by AVR libc and aren't specific to the Arduino platform. There's a reference page on them [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html).

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Still puzzled why it's not listed in Arduino doc that includes other data types that part of AVR libc.